# How do I enable logging for Spring Schedule annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I am trying to debug some issues in some of our cron jobs that use `@Schedule`. The following link suggests turning on logging for `org.springframework.scheduling.*`. https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/methods-annotated-with-scheduled-stops-working?language=en_US I have tried this a few ways in the yaml with no additional logs showing up.

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    com.netflix.discovery.shared.resolver.aws.ConfigClusterResolver: WARN
    org.springframework.scheduling: DEBUG
```

I have tried

```
org.springframework.scheduling: DEBUG
org.springframework.*: DEBUG
org.springframework.scheduling.annotation: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

When using application.properties add the following to your config file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.scheduling=TRACE
```

Comment: This only seems to log at the very beginning when it's looking for @Scheduled annotations on classes. 
It doesn't log anything at all with regard to actually running tasks. Any idea if there _is_ actually any more logging?